# Is there a way to list all DLLs loaded in Windows by ALL processes using Python?

Tags: python, windows, dll, process

I want to use Python to get a list of all DLLs loaded by *every* process on Windows

In PowerShell, I can do:

```
Get-Process | Select -Expand Modules
```

Is there a way I can do this in Python, using a Windows api, without spawning a command shell (e.g. I want to avoid doing `subprocess.popen(...)`)?

Comment: Do you need ctypes, or is a dependency on PyWin32 ok?

Comment: Honestly I'm not familiar with python enough to address your question. I just want to be able to see the DLLs loaded by all processes (whether a python program or not).

Comment: PyWin32 is a package of extension modules that wrap the Windows API and COM. It's a rather large dependency, so for scripts that should be more lightweight you might prefer to use ctypes, even though it requires more work to define the WinAPI structures and function prototypes.

Comment: In that case, ctypes. I'm improting `win32pdh` to get all process information, so I thought I could use that same library for those processes' DLLs.

Comment: `win32pdh` is part of PyWin32.

Comment: Great -- did you have a solution in mind?

Comment: Sure, but it won't be using win32pdh; I don't think there are any process performance counters for loaded modules. You have to individually query the loaded modules for each process -- and accept that some system processes won't allow this because they're secured by ACLs or created as protected processes. For example, `tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq smss.exe"` prints N/A for the loaded modules since the session manager process is protected.

Answer (score 0):

The following `list_processes` generator uses PyWin32 to call [`EnumProcesses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629) and [`EnumProcessModulesEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682633). I've written it to temporarily enable `SeDebugPrivilege` in order to get virtual-memory read access for as many processes as possible. An elevated administrator should have this privilege.

```
import os
import win32con
import win32api
import win32process
import win32security
import collections

PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = 0x1000

def adjust_privilege(name, attr=win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED):
    if isinstance(name, str):
        state = (win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, name), attr)
    else:
        state = name
    hToken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32process.GetCurrentProcess(),
                win32security.TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS)
    return win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, False, [state])

def get_process_modules(hProcess):
    imagepath = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, None)
    imagepath_upper = imagepath.upper()
    modules = []
    for hModule in win32process.EnumProcessModulesEx(hProcess,
                        win32process.LIST_MODULES_ALL):
        modulepath = win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hModule)
        if modulepath.upper() != imagepath_upper:
            modules.append(modulepath)
    return imagepath, sorted(modules)

Process = collections.namedtuple('Process', 'name path pid modules')

def list_processes():
    prev_state = adjust_privilege(win32security.SE_DEBUG_NAME)
    try:
        for pid in win32process.EnumProcesses():
            hProcess = None
            path = ''
            modules = []
            if pid == 0:
                name = 'System Idle Process'
            elif pid == 4:
                name = 'System'
            else:
                try:
                    hProcess = win32api.OpenProcess(
                        PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION |
                        win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ,
                        False, pid)
                except win32api.error:
                    try:
                        hProcess = win32api.OpenProcess(
                            PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
                            False, pid)
                    except win32api.error as e:
                        pass
                if hProcess:
                    try:
                        path, modules = get_process_modules(hProcess)
                    except win32process.error:
                        pass
                name = os.path.basename(path)
            yield Process(name, path, pid, modules)
    finally:
        if prev_state:
            adjust_privilege(prev_state[0])
```